# Backing up iPhoto pictures and folders from the command-line

Tags: backup, photos.app, command-line, ssh

I'd like to install a new OS X on a MacBook and I'd like to know what needs to be done to backup *only* the iPhoto pictures.  I definitely do *not* want to backup the entire /Users/Cedric/ directory.  All I need is my iPhoto pictures and all the iPhoto "folders".

Ideally I'd like to do this over the network using ssh / scp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your whole iPhoto library is stored in `~/Pictures/iPhoto Library`. If you look at it in the Finder it appears as a single file but it's actually a package (aka directory structure). So in order to back it up over ssh/scp you can use one of

- `scp -r ~/Pictures/iPhoto\ Library user@remote_host:`
- `rsync -a -e ssh ~/Pictures/iPhoto\ Library remote_host:`